# Flutter infinite scroll - Scroll listener triggers

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am building an infinite list view where I make a backend call every time the user has reached a certain position in their feed (say nearing 90%). I am using a ScrollController and attach something like this function to the listener :

```
void _onScroll() {

    var triggerFetchMoreSize =
        0.9 * _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    if (_scrollController.position.pixels >
        triggerFetchMoreSize) {
      print("fetch more after you reached 90% ");
    }

  }
```

But this is being triggered multiple times over a feed scroll. The same exact request can be triggered if the user scrolls up and down. How can I deal with this ?

How can I make sure I only make a single backend request for every correct trigger (like one initial request + only one when the user scrolls to around 90% of the current feed + ... )

Comment: cache your requests somewhere, for example by using `MapCache` - the docs say: *"All access to a Cache is asynchronous because many implementations will store their entries in remote systems, isolates, or otherwise have to do async IO to read and write"*

Comment: You can also just store it in widget state. You could store fe. last url you fetched or id and compare it before doing a request

Answer (score 0):

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // connect(sourceUser);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      var triggerFetchMoreSize =
          0.7 * _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;

      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        print(10);
        pagination();
      }
    });
  
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Please use dispose method to stop from loading multiple times.